# How does the Unity tweak tool work when Gnome is installed?

Tags: unity, gnome, unity-tweak-tool

So I've read that Gnome and Unity are alternatives to one another. And if I check the details section of my settings I can see that Gnome 3.28.2 is installed. Why is it then that I can still configure aspects of Ubuntu with the Unity tweak tool? Usually, I'd expect an error upon launch.

Comment: Unity is based on Gnome3, so that it shouldn't be surprising, the two share a lot of the code. In essence, UT is just a friendly front end for gsettings framework.

Comment: @mikewhatever Why not post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Unity is based on Gnome3, so that it shouldn't be surprising, the two share a lot of code. 
In essence, UT is just a friendly front end for the gsettings framework, and you could achieve the same effect with `gsettings set ...somepath ...somekey`

That said, Unity related settings probably wouldn't work.